# Redes locales, routers, configuración

Tags: router, red

Tengo que configurar un router Tplink WR740N detrás de otro router Cisco RVS4000. La idea es crear dos segmentos de una misma red. Por ejemplo, Para el Cisco RVS4000 que está detrás del modem (192.168.1.1) y para el Tplink WR740N (192.168.2.1). Con estas premisas he configurado el Tplink en su puerto WAN (IP estática) 192.168.1.10 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.1.1 (IP, mascará, getaway) y para el puerto LAN 192.168.2.1 | 255.255.255.0. Adicionalmente, configure el DHCP con los siguientes parámetros 192.168.2.100~253 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.2.1. El problema es que cuando lo conecto a la red interna no puede ser accedido (si está en línea, mediante ping) y tampoco tiene conexión a Internet. ¿Qué puede estar pasando? Gracias

Comment: Te está faltando indicarle que el tráfico a internet lo debe redirigir por el router Cisco. De la misma forma, para el tema de que ambos segmentos "se vean", tendrás que uno de los dos routers que no "conoce" la otra red ... a ese router (seguramente el Cisco), tendrás que añadirle una ruta para que sepa redirigir correctamente los paquetes que van al otro segmento de red

Comment: Suena a que el TP lo quieres en [*Modo Puente*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puente_de_red).

Comment: Hola, Mil gracias por responder a mi pregunta. El TPLink no está en modo puente. ¿Cómo puedo indicar el tráfico? ¿Sobre el TPLink o sobre el Cisco? ¿Cómo puedo indicarle la ruta de una subred al router? Gracias